# Why "if (unsigned int == string::npos )" CAN be true?

Tags: c++

Let me start by saying: I'm sorry if this was explained, I tried reading about it and searching for answer but I didn't find one that answered **this specific** question.

So I'm writing beginner's level code in C++ and I wrote a very simple function that returns index of the next found character that isn't space. It was inspired by the method string.find().
If the function doesn't find anything it returns string::npos.

```
int findChar (const string &line, const int startPos){
    for (unsigned int i= startPos; i < line.length(); i++){
        if ( line[i] != ' ') return i;
    }
    return string::npos;
}
```

Now, because I'm working on strings and indices, I thought of using a unsigned int.

```
unsigned int where;
where = findChar(line, 0);
```

And because "where" is an unsigned int I thought comparison of "where == string::npos" is a bad idea because string::npos is initialized with -1, and unsigned int can't be equal to -1. But if the function doesn't find anything and it returns string::npos the condition can be true, the program recognizes that "unsigned int where" is string::npos, but when I try to print "where" out, it prints out as biggest number unsigned int can hold.

So my question is why, or how, the program can recognize unsigned int to be equal to string::npos, even though technically string::npos is initialized with value of -1.

I'm trying to learn so if you can point me to some reading material that also answers this I'd be grateful.

Comment: Print `std::string::npos`, you'll be surprised. Note that your code "works" only on 32-bit platforms, where `std::size_t` has the same size as `unsigned int`.

Comment: string::npos is defined as `static const size_t npos = -1;` but `std::size_t is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator`  So when -1 is assigned to a size_t object it is converted to an unsigned value with the same bit pattern as -1.

Comment: [1.](https://en.cppreference.com/), [2.](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&biw=1600&bih=789&sxsrf=ALeKk03cdliNz4aF942LdWI1YSSozg6GNg%3A1611167052843&ei=THUIYN_6MuOMlwS1hoHoDA&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+std%3A%3Astring%3A%3Anpos&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+std%3A%3Astring%3A%3Anpos&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1C4-awFWLKkrQVgsrStBWgAcAJ4AIABsQKIAfETkgEIMy4xMC4yLjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjf0O7-kKvuAhVjxoUKHTVDAM0Q4dUDCA0&uact=5), [3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) This should be kept in order please.

Comment: That function `findChar` is weird. It returns `int`, while `i` is `unsigned int` and `std::string::npos` is `size_t`.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The bit pattern may be different (and is, on a 64-bit system, or a non 2's complement system). The conversion is defined in terms of value under modular arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string::npos` is a large positive number .

To avoid these issues, your function's return type should match the type of the value you are returning, e.g.:

- return `string::size_type` instead of `int`, or:
- return some other failure sentinel such as `-1` in the first code.

The way you have it now, there can always be a clash when the "adjusted" value to fit in the return type happens to be the same as a valid return value.

Although `npos` *might be* initialized with `-1` in an implementation header,  that doesn't mean its value is `-1`. The initializer is converted to the type of the object being initialized, which is `string::size_type`, guaranteed to be an unsigned type.  The result of this conversion is a large positive value.

---

NB. Your code will break miserably if called on a string longer than `UINT_MAX` characters, since the `i` loop never ends. The `i` should also be `string::size_type` rather than `int`;  and  similar considerations apply to the `startPos` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

If you read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos):

> Although the definition uses -1, size_type is an unsigned integer type, and the value of npos is the largest positive value it can hold, due to signed-to-unsigned implicit conversion. This is a portable way to specify the largest value of any unsigned type.

Note: `std::string::npos` is of type `size_t`. Using anything else may be undefined behaviour and is **not advised**.

Comment: Using other types might not work, but I think it's not UB per se.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Isn't that precisely what "might not work" means in practice?

Comment: @tadman UB has a well-defined meaning (perhaps ironically), there can be code which does not behave as intended, but is not Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @M.M Unless you can find a place where storing `npos` in anything other than its intended type is *defined* then I'd suggest it is *undefined*. I'm sure there's some conversions allowed via other explicit rules, but there aren't many things that are able to represent `size_t` without issues.

Comment: @tadman I can indeed find such place -- out-of-range conversion from unsigned to signed integer type is specified as *implementation-defined*

Comment: @M.M Not sure how that applies in this case when going from, say, `size_t` to some arbitrary-length `unsigned int`. Compiler-specific outcome? I did say it "may" be undefined behaviour to cover this case.

Comment: Out-of-range conversion to unsigned integer is well-defined; the value is adjusted via modular arithmetic until it is in range

Comment: @M.M Not sure there's a situation where `X y = std::string::npos` still preserves `y == std::string::npos` for any `X` not nearly identical to the definition of `size_t`. You can crunch things into range, but can you uncrunch them to match the original out-of-range value during a comparison?

Comment: @tadman it's not undefined behaviour, regardless of the answer to that question